# Hide select options with css

Tags: html, css

I would like to hide a select form option using CSS but I can't figure out how to do this.

I have a form like this and I need to remove the "before" option.

I expect that `option[value=before]{display:none!important}` will hide it but it appears it does not work.

```css
option[value=before] {
  display: none!important
}
```

```html
<select class="_select">
  <option value="">Any</option>
  <option value="1d">Today</option>
  <option value="7d">This Week</option>
  <option value="31d">This month</option>
  <option selected="" value="before">Before date</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Seems like it works...

Comment: Well I guess it is hidden in the select but you can still see it as the selected value

Comment: Hiding options via `display:none` is not correctly supported in both IE and Edge. If you need it to work in those browsers, then _removing_ the option from the DOM is the only proper (no pun intended) ... option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `""` :`[value="before"]`

If you want to hide it from `select` remove `selected=""` from   `<option selected="" value="before">Before date</option>`

```css
option[value="before"]{
display:none;
}
```

```html
<select class="_select">
  <option value="">Indifférente</option>
  <option value="1d">Today</option>
  <option value="7d">This Week</option>
  <option value="31d">This month</option>
  <option  value="before">Before date</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Does this work on your browser? because it doesn't on my FF and chrome

Comment: yse! do you mean to hide it also from `select` ?

Comment: try to set `class` to wanted option and use in css `.wanted{display:none}`

Comment: I think you mean use quotes around the value of the attribute, but it's not terribly apparent as it is. Might not be a bad idea to quote (pardon the pun) from the standard too (https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#attribute-selectors along with  https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#strings showing that strings are always in quotes.

Comment: Apparently even adding inline : <option  value="before" style="display:none;">Before date</option> doesn't work.
Looks like select option doesn't support display property :(

Comment: Setting a class doesn't help either. So I think this is not possible.

Comment: In the same time there are 3 upvotes on your answer, so it works for you ??

Comment: Ok I accept this but note this has not worked for me. Thank you anyway.

Comment: can you show me a picture of your F12 style maybe something override your css